# Title of the dialog is too high

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How can I reduce the height of the green title?

Activity:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(EditorActivity.this, R.style.dialog);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.preference_timerange);
dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.zmien_czas_wyprawy));
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/dialog_title_style</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dialog_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dialog_text</item>
</style>

<style name="dialog_title_style" parent="android:TextAppearance.WindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/dialog_title_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dialog_title_text</item>
</style>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to change the height of the Dialog's title, but you can remove the whole title and create a smaller one in your layout `preference_timerange.xml`:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(EditorActivity.this, R.style.dialog);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.preference_timerange);

// Set R.string.zmien_czas_wyprawy as the title in your layout now
```